# Web2PY caching password

Tags: python

I'm just starting to use Web2PY. 
My basic one page app authenticates users to a AD based LDAP service. 
I need to collect other data via rest api calls on behave of the user from the server side of the app. 
I'd like to cache the username and password of the user for a session so the user doesn't have to be prompted for credentials multiple times. 
Is there an easy way to do this ?

Comment: why don't you just pass the session_key in the request?

Comment: Is a session key actually the password for the user in active directory / LDAP?  I thought the session key was just a unique value for the life of the app in the browser?

Comment: no it is not the password.. every time on user login event a session is created. this session is represented by a session_key. Sessions are used to maintain authentication ... i dont know how web2py handles this but this is basicAuth 101.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to close out on this in case someone in the future is looking at this as well.

I was able to capture the password used to login by adding the following to my db.py

def on_ldap_connect(form):
  username = request.vars.username
  password = request.vars.password

*You can save user/password to some session variable or secure file to 
use for authenticating to other services.*

auth.settings.login_onaccept.append(on_ldap_connect)